# Python, set log level in Django project, deployed with gunicorn and 4 workers

Tags: python, django, logging, gunicorn

I recently met a logging issue about set logging level.
I have a demo django project, which is to test set log level. below is the page:

[image]

The log will be written to /tmp/run.log.

When I deploy it with gunicoryn + nginx(proxy static file), and has 4 gunicorn workes. Set log level only have effect to one of the workers:

[image]

[image]

Above the two pictures, I set log level to `ERROR`, but only effect worker 74096.

Here are some information and Django code.

- System Info:

  System: Centos 7.4 x64 
  Python: 2.7.5
  Django: 1.11.2
  Gunicorn: 19.7.1
- Django logging config:

  ```
  LOGGING = {
      'version': 1,
      'disable_existing_loggers': False,
      'formatters': {
          'verbose': {
              'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
          }
      },
      'handlers': {
          'file': {
              'level': 'DEBUG',
              'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
              'maxBytes': 1024,
              'backupCount': 5,
              'filename': '/tmp/run.log',
              'formatter': 'verbose'
          },
          'console': {
              'level': 'DEBUG',
              'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
              'formatter': 'verbose'
  ```
- set log level function

  ```
  name = "django_docker"
  bind = "unix:/var/run/django_docker.sock"
  worker_class = "egg:meinheld#gunicorn_worker"
  #workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
  workers = 4
  reload = True

  umask = 0002
  user = 'nginx'
  group = 'nginx'

  accesslog = "/tmp/gunicorn.access.log"
  errorlog = "/tmp/gunicorn.error.log"

  raw_env = ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_docker.settings"]
  chdir = " /home/user/workspace/django_docker/"
  pidfile = "/var/run/gunicorn.pid"
  daemon = True

  logconfig_dict = {
      'version':1,
      'disable_existing_loggers': False,
      'loggers':{
          "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["console"]},
          "gunicorn.error": {
              "level": "INFO",
              "handlers": ["error_file"],
              "propagate": 1,
              "qualname": "gunicorn.error"
          },

          "gunicorn.access": {
              "level": "INFO",
              "handlers": ["access_file"],
              "propagate": 0,
              "qualname": "gunicorn.access"
          }
      },
      'handlers':{
          "console": {
              "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
              "formatter": "generic",
              "stream": "sys.stdout"
          },
          "error_file": {
              "class": "logging.FileHandler",
              "formatter": "generic",
              "filename": "/tmp/gunicorn.error.log"
          },
          "access_file": {
              "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
              "maxBytes": 1024*1024,
              "backupCount": 5,
              "formatter": "generic",
              "filename": "/tmp/gunicorn.access.log",
          }
      },
      'formatters':{
          "generic": {
              "format": "%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
              "datefmt": "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z]",
              "class": "logging.Formatter"
          },
          "access": {
              "format": "%(message)s",
              "class": "logging.Formatter"
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Also, I have try to deploy with uwsgi and 4 workers, Also have the problem.

Could anyone help with me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you run gunicorn with 4 workers, it actually **creates 4 separate django applications** for you.

then, when a request comes to gunicorn, it passes the request to **just 1 of your 4** django applications.(for example for balancing the load on 4 django apps so one is not under pressure and other 3 sit freely without work)

so when you are accessing the 8001 port of your host and sending a request to server, just one of the 4 apps receive it and process it for its own. other 3 apps have their own separate memory and dont see the setting of other app.

you can check this behavior by setting a variable in your app and then getting it back. for instance you have i=0 as default and then you set i=1 in one app and then request a page which contains the i value. because maybe another app has handled the i=1 command, you have a chance to see value for i is 0. try refreshing the page and you have a chance to see i is 1. each time a different app is answering your request with its own memory and data.

**as a solution** you can use a memory which is external to django apps. for example store your setting or other params in a redis db. when you need that setting, get it from redis and when you want to change it, change it on redis. this way, all 4 apps are using a shared redis db memory.

Comment: thanks you solution, I will try to save the env to memory. And now I found that run gunicorn with 4 threads also can fix this.

Comment: @jolla this might be helpful about threads and workers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425620/gunicorn-workers-and-threads