# How does gevent ensure that the same thread-local variables are not shared between multiple coroutines

Tags: python, django, thread-safety, coroutine, gevent

I have a Python 2 django project, which was started with gunicorn, and write a lot of `threading.currentThread().xxxxxx ='some value'` in the code.

Because the coroutine reuses the same thread, I am curious how gevent guarantees that the currentThread variable created in coroutine A(**Thread 1**) will not affect coroutine B (**same Thread 1**).

After all, the writing on the code is:

```py
import threading
threading.currentThread().xxxxx ='ABCD'
```

Instead of

```py
import gevent
gevent.currentCoroutine().xxxxx ='ABCD' (simulate my guess)
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't as far as I'm aware. Normal Gevent coroutines run in the same thread - if you modify something on that thread in one coroutine, it will be modified in the other coroutine as well.

If this is a question about gunicorn, that's a different matter and the following answer has some great detail on that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41696500/7970018.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `threading.local`in mainThread.
After monkey patching, Gevent patched `gevent.local = threading.local` so you can save data in current via:

```
import threading

threadlocal = threading.local()

def func_in_thread():
    # set data
    setattr(threadlocal, "_key", "_value")
    # do something
    # do something
    getattr(threadlocal, "_key", None)
```